# Ubuntu 12.04.04 LTS xfs xlog_space_left

Tags: 12.04, lvm, xfs

I am running Kernel: 3.2.0-59-generic will moving to 3.2.0-61-generic fix the issue with xlog_space_left: head behind tail? I do a serious amount of lvsnap shots every hour on a mysql database on a Solid State Drive. The XFS is on top of LVM. which then I mount the snapshot to rsync to another server.

Should I run an xfs_check? or reboot and will it fix it? or should I patch the OS to the latest version of the kernel?

These are the mount options for the XFS file system I am using:

```
/etc/fstab < file >

/dev/mapper/SysVolGroup-lvdb /db            xfs     inode64,noatime,discard        0       2
```

Should I keep these mount options or should I use something different for SSD drives I am using.